# scala => javafx pop-up

Tags: scala

I would like to create a pop-in in scala with javafx

```
final val popup = new Popup  
val text: Text = new Text(s)
popup.setAutoFix(false)
popup.setHideOnEscape(true)
popup.getContent().addAll(text)
popup.setX(250)
popup.setY(175)
popup.show(stage)
```

but I have one error

```
org.view.View@72d873: caught java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
```

someone have an idea?

thank

Comment: Which thread are you trying to show the popup on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably invoke the `show` method on the FX Application thread, as the error suggests.

This happens because the code that modifies the UI must be executed on a specific UI thread (the same happens for  Swing and other GUI frameworks), to prevent concurrent updates and guarantee consistency of the UI components.

Usually these modifications are already made on the correct thread, which is the one that executes the callback code for the UI event listeners, but if you need to access the UI from another thread you must schedule it on the FX Application thread with a call to

[javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Runnable r)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

as in

```
runLater (new Runnable() {
    def run = popup.show(stage)
})
```